# selecting ID's with a code not equal to X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of IDs and a list of codes.  The relationship is 1:many. One ID can have multiple codes. I want to select any IDs that are not equal to 3, but I do want to select IDs if they contain 3 while also being equal to something else.

For example: 
    ID:         Codes:
    A           1,2,4
    B           1,2,3
    C           3

I want to select code A because it doesn't contain 3.
I want to select code B because although it contains 3 it also contains things not equal to 3.
I DON'T want code C because it only contains 3.

I tried selecting Ids not like '3' but obviously that excludes IDs i want that contain other codes

```
    select ID
    from table 
    where ID not in (
                       select ID 
                       from table
                       where code like '3'
                     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ids that are not all `'3'`, from what I can tell.

```
select distinct id
from t
where code <> '3';
```

If you want to keep the original rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.code <> '3');
```

Comment: i believe this still excludes IDs that have codes of '3' plus other things. If it contains '2' and '3' i want to keep it